# enabling a checkbox when another checkbox is checked using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to enable a disabled checkbox when another checkbox is checked by using javascript. I believe my problem is when I am trying to pass the form information into the javascript.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <form id="checkboxes">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxa" onclick="javascript:ToggleSwitch(form)" />1
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxb" disabled="true" />2
        </form>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var form= document.getElementById("checkboxes")
function ToggleSwitch(form) {
    if (form.elements["checkboxa"].checked) 
   form.elements["checkboxb"].disabled = false
} else {
   form.elements["checkboxb"].disabled = true
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `{` and `}` in your javascript. Try this:

```
var form= document.getElementById("checkboxes")
function ToggleSwitch(form) {
    if (form.elements["checkboxa"].checked) { // here
       form.elements["checkboxb"].disabled = false
    } else {
       form.elements["checkboxb"].disabled = true
    }
} // and here
```

Comment: That was it! What a dumb oversight on my part. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Change you onclick event like this

```
onclick="javascript:ToggleSwitch(this.form)"
```

and also you don't need to `var form= document.getElementById("checkboxes")` since you are already passing it as a parameter from onclick event.

And you are also missing a parenthesis

Here is the js

```
  <script>
    function ToggleSwitch(form) {
        if (form.elements["checkboxa"].checked) {
            form.elements["checkboxb"].disabled = false
        } else {
            form.elements["checkboxb"].disabled = true
        }
    }

</script>
```

And here is the html

```
  <form id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxa" onclick="javascript:ToggleSwitch(this.form)" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxb" disabled="disabled" />2
</form>
```

And here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HmYK7/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've got syntax errors in your javascript (missing `{` in the `if` statement).

You also have some redundancy in your function. It is essentially this pattern:

```
if (x) { return true; } else { return false; };
```

which can be simplified to

```
return x;
```

Here is a slightly different method, taking these points into account, and also removing the need to search the whole document for ids (which usually makes things more portable/reusable).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ToggleSwitch(el, other) {
        el.form.elements[other].disabled = !el.checked;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="checkboxes">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxa" onclick="ToggleSwitch(this, 'checkboxb')" />1
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxb" disabled="true" />2
    </form>
  </body>
<html>
```